# Xamarin.Essentials.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException when trying to use Connectivity.NetworkAccess

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to check if the android device has internet access. For that im trying to use Connectivity.NetworkAccess from Xamarin.Essentials. When I call it in my App however i get this Error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Xamarin.Essentials.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException: This
> functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
> assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main
> application project in order to reference the platform-specific
> implementation.

I have downloaded the Xamarin.Essentials NuGet in both my main project and the android project. (I am not using UWP or IOS). I already tried reinstalling and rebuilding but I still get the same error.

Any Ideas how I can fix this error?

Comment: Have you installed Xamarin.Essentials on both your xamarin forms and xamarin android projects? Also remember that you must give access permission to network state on android as suggested in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android)

Comment: Did you install the NuGet package on both your shared project as well as your platform projects?